# PhD latex thesis with bibliography per chapter

Tags: bibliographies

Good morning everyone. I am a new member of this great community where people share ideas, advices...I am a PhD student and I just started to write
my thesis. I am actually using the cued template (from this website:
http://www-h.eng.cam.ac.uk/help/tpl/tex ... esisStyle/). With this
template, the whole bibliography is at the end of the manuscript, just like
many others I have seen. I rather prefer a bibliography per chapter (at the
end of each chapter) for a better structure of the manuscript. I used usepackage[sectionbib]{chapterbib}, or so many things to have a bibliography per chapter, but it does not work. I feel like the cued template I am using, is made for only one bibliography. My question is how can I fix it? or where can I get a latex phd template with the bibliography per chapter? Can you please help? tell me anything...? Thank you for any explanation. Hope you very soon.

Comment: Morning. My advice would be to *not* use that template if you are not attendig that school/university/institute.

Comment: OK. Thank you for the tip. I was expecting something more like a a suggestion of a template...thank you anyway...

Comment: Afaik you can add a `\addbibliography` at the place you want it, and modify the bibliography inclusion such that you get only the referenced links (while retaining the whole bibliography for the whole document)

Comment: @rogwar: Furthermore: Use the template your university provides you, don't use something else (or simply write your own...)

Comment: [Crosspost](http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?p=93663#p936630)

Comment: @arc_lupus institution-provided templates are rare in the UK. Which is probably a good thing as those that are provided are often dreadful.